# WPF control for OSM without a webserver

Tags: c#, wpf, openstreetmap

I'm planning to use the control to read from a flat .txt file that has lat and long and while staying centered on the currently displayed coordinate, draw a track and pan the map to center on the next passed in coordinate. I should also be able to control the pan rate.So by the end of the run I'll have a line from start to finish. I would also like to use onboard data as internet access is hard to come by(shape files from http://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html sound about right)

It seems simple, but I've run into trouble as to what control I should use. Most of the controls either are WinForms, want a web server, and/or only want some sort of database for the coordinates. Did I miss a control?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [this control](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/). It displays all kinds of tiled map content like OpenStreetMap and allows to be operated in offline environments. This is achieved by caching map tiles into a local database or as image files into the local filesystem. There is however no mechanism yet that would create a pre-filled cached and, depending on the area and zoom level you intend to cover, the cache might get huge.

Comment: The control almost fits my needs in that it does have a decently simple line drawing function and will take in points from a txt. Unfortunately I cannot rely on the app having any sort of internet connectivity out of the box...while I could pre populate the internal database it seems like a inelegant solution when I could just use shape files. So the search continues...thanks though.

Comment: now redirects to https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/ (renamed to XAML Map Control). Caching is only available for the WPF version